# Android ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable only works once?

Tags: android, seekbar

In a color picker, I have 3 SeekBars for Hue, Saturation, and Value.  Calling setProgressDrawable on these SeekBars only works once -- at initialization from onCreate.  When the user updates the Hue SeekBar, I want to call setProgressDrawable for the Saturation and Value SeekBars, to show the user their color choices for the new Hue.

But all calls to setProgressDrawable (after the initial ones from `onCreate`) cause the SeekBar to be blanked.

How can I update the background gradient of my SeekBars based upon user input?

Answer (score 43):

What I found out is that the drawable doesn't know it's size when setprogressdrawable is called. When it is initially set up, it does know it's size. This means there is a new drawable set to the seekbar, but the size of the drawable is 0, you won't see anything.

The solution is to first get the bounds of the current drawable, then set the new drawable and finally set the bounds again:

```
Rect bounds = mySeekBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
mySeekBar.setProgressDrawable(newSeekBarBackground);
mySeekBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: This was similar but slightly different than the issue I ran into. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336939/seekbar-drawable-not-drawn-after-being-reused-by-adapter. Adding a comment here in case it helps someone someday

Comment: To work for me I did what you said and add that:
mySeekBar.setProgress(mySeekBar.getProgress()+1);
mySeekBar.setProgress(mySeekBar.getProgress()-1);
Doing that I force a move, but stay in the same position.

Comment: To work for me I set progress in xml equal to max: `android:max="500" android:progress="500"`

Comment: If your Progress Bar is indeterminate then you should call `setIndeterminateDrawable` instead of `setProgressDrawable`.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got the solutions to this, you first have to set the drawable to the ProgressBar by calling setProgresssDrawable(drawable) and only then set the value and not vice versa. That'll work.

To set a progress drawable:

Use a drawable xml file like this one:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient android:startColor="#00CCCC"
            android:centerColor="#00CCCC" android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#00CCCC" android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient android:startColor="#00CCCC"
                android:centerColor="#00CCCC" android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#00CCCC" android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient android:startColor="#00CCCC" android:centerColor="#00CCCC"
                android:centerY="0.75" android:endColor="#00CCCC" android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

save this into your /drawable folder and use it in the setProgressDrawable(drawable) function

Comment: How can I set the color of the gradient of the Progress Drawable?

Comment: I have answered your question above!

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't resolve the problem of the OP. See toneffectory answer.

Comment: This might not have helped the OP, but it surely helped me.