# How to dynamically change the color of progress bar background android

Tags: android, colors, progress-bar

I'd like to dynamically change the background color of a progress bar in android. I followed the "bonus" part near the end of the page of this tutorial:

http://colintmiller.com/2010/10/how-to-add-text-over-a-progress-bar-on-android/

It changes the color, but only once. If called more than once, the progress bar disappears. Here's the code.

Here's the progress bar definition:

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_bar" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

This is the drawable definition in res/drawable/green_progress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/greenStart"
                    android:centerColor="@color/greenMid"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="@color/greenEnd"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Ene entries to rex/values/colors.xml:

```
<color name="greenStart">#ff33dd44</color>
<color name="greenMid">#ff0A8815</color>
<color name="greenEnd">#ff1da130</color>
```

And finally, in the code:

```
m_bar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_progress));
```

Again, the problem is it works the first time, but then makes the bar disappear.

Comment: What is the exact name of the file containing the drawable definition? Your question says that its 'res/drawable/green_xml', but you're setting the drawable to R.drawable.green_progress. I'd expect your file name to be 'res/drawable/green_progress.xml' if your setting the drawable to R.drawable.green_progress

Comment: Thanks, that's right. I've just corrected it.

Comment: Where are you calling m_bar.setProgressDrawable(...)? Are you doing it inside onCreate(..)?

Comment: @james - unfortunately, no, it was just a typo on the post.

Comment: @james - I'm setting it initially in a method called from onResume, but subsequently that same method called from a button click.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See [Android ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable only works once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805866/android-progressbar-setprogressdrawable-only-works-once) for the answer, repeated below:

What I found out is that the drawable doesn't know it's size when setprogressdrawable is called. When it is initially set up, it does know it's size. This means there is a new drawable set to the seekbar, but the size of the drawable is 0, you won't see anything.

The solution is to first get the bounds of the current drawable, then set the new drawable and finally set the bounds again:

```
Rect bounds = mySeekBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
mySeekBar.setProgressDrawable(newSeekBarBackground);
mySeekBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do to begin with. I've, actually run into this same exact problem/fix while trying to do custom map overlays. Different situation, but the same underlying problem of the Drawable not know it's size. +1

Comment: James, did figure out this problem earlier? I went to the source code of ProgressBar, but it did a couple of vague looking things that seemed tough to follow, i.e. requestLayout(), and postInvalididate(). I'd like to know how you tracked the solution for future reference. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, I tracked the issue down with a combination of the debugger and the hierarchy viewer tool. After displaying my ImageView (which was using the drawable), i looked up the view in hierarchyviewer to make sure it was there, which it was. I noticed the dimensions on it were 0. Then I did a search on stack overflow.

Comment: Ah, right. So you've loaded the Android source code for the debugger? Maybe I should give that a try.

Comment: No, I didn't load the android source code for debugging. I just stepped through my own code, where I was dynamically adding views. The debugging had more to do with making sure things were happening correctly, which they were, it was more the hierarchy viewer that led me down the 0-dimension path. The debugger is always where I turn first though. However, if you want to understand what 'invalidate()' and those other methods do, debugging the source is definitely the way to go. Happy spelunking :)

Answer (score 11):

Well, for anyone looking for how to do it programmatically:

```
    Drawable bckgrndDr = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
    Drawable secProgressDr = new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY);
    Drawable progressDr = new ScaleDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), Gravity.LEFT, 1, -1);
    LayerDrawable resultDr = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { bckgrndDr, secProgressDr, progressDr });

    resultDr.setId(0, android.R.id.background);
    resultDr.setId(1, android.R.id.secondaryProgress);
    resultDr.setId(2, android.R.id.progress);

    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(resultDr);
```

Setting ids to drawables is crucial, and takes care of preserving bounds and actual state of progress bar

Comment: works perfects. Just  follow this code and change the colors as required.