# ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable not working for Android 2.3

Tags: android

I am currently working with a dynamically updating `ProgressBar`.  Through certain percentages, the progessbar sets a drawable of a different color.  We currently have various colored clip drawable defined in a drawable xml.  The one entitled `progressbar_blue_states` is detailed as follows:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item android:id="@android:id/background"
      android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_grey">
  </item>

  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
      <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_blue" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Whenever we need to update the dialog, we call the following code:

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar_blue_states));
```

However, not only does this not update the ProgressBar, but also it takes out the progress bar altogether where whitespace is left in it's place.  However, if I set `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_blue_states"` in the xml and take out this `setProgressDrawable()` call, it loads correctly.  We need the setProgressDrawable to update the colors as needed.

This call works fine in Android 4.0+ however in Android 2.3 we're running into some trouble.  Any ideas?

**Edit**

This is how we set up the ProgressBar in the xml:

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:indeterminateOnly="false"
            android:progress="24"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_red_states" />
```

Comment: Did you tried updating the bounds for the `progressbar_blue` when setting it as the progress drawable?

Comment: Do you mean setting the progress amount? If so, we do that immediately after setting the drawable.

Comment: If you mean the layout bounds, do that in the xml, which I added above.

Comment: No, I was referring to the drawable's bounds(which is done starting with 4.0 among other things). Like this: `Drawable newDr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar_blue_states); newdr.setBounds(0, 0, progressbar.getWidth() - progressbar.getPaddingLeft() - progressbar.getPaddingRight(), progressbar.getHeight() - progressbar.getPaddingTop() -progressbar.getPaddingBottom()); progressbar.setProgressDrawable(newDr);`?

Comment: ok, that got us closer.  We now have the outline for the background (android:id = background) but the progress isn't filling in (android:id = progress).  Is the clip interfering with this?

Comment: I don't think the clip has anything to do with that(especially as in the xml it works). I've setup some code replicating(almost, I hope I haven't left out the important part:) ) how the method looks on newer versions here https://gist.github.com/luksprog/5213888 . See if it works.

Comment: It still seems to have the same problem as before.  The background loads, but the progress coloring does not.

Comment: Can you post how the `progressbar_blue` looks like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26654/discussion-between-jbenowitz-and-luksprog)

Answer (score 9):

I have got the same bug, but it is solved by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220910/how-to-dynamically-change-the-color-of-progress-bar-background-android)

This means there is a new drawable set to the seekbar, but the size of the drawable is 0, you won't see anything.

```
Rect bounds = mySeekBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
mySeekBar.setProgressDrawable(newSeekBarBackground);
mySeekBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue and this was the solution.

Answer (score 4):

According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6953534/3223742

a good solution is to set progress to 1; re-set max progress, and then set the real progress :

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(...);
progressBar.setProgress(1);
progressBar.setMax(maxProgress);
progressBar.setProgress(progress);
```