# Progress not showing after changing drawable

Tags: android

I have this class which configures the image of drawable after every click.

```
*******
int mProgressBar;
int mProgressBarBg;
boolean check = true;
ProgressBar progress;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progress.setProgress(50);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(check) {
                mProgressBarBg = R.drawable.bg_bar_progress;
                mProgressBar = R.drawable.progress_quest_green;
                check = false;
            } else {
                mProgressBarBg = R.drawable.bg_bar_progress_orange;
                mProgressBar = R.drawable.progress_quest_orange;
                check = true;
            }
            findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setBackgroundResource(mProgressBarBg);
            Drawable colorDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(mProgressBar);
            Rect bounds = progress.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
            progress.setProgressDrawable(colorDrawable);
            progress.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
        }
    });
}
*******
```

Problem:
Progress not showing after click. How can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

this might help: [Android ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable only works once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805866/android-progressbar-setprogressdrawable-only-works-once)

this answer:
***"To work for me I did what you said and add that: mySeekBar.setProgress(mySeekBar.getProgress()+1); mySeekBar.setProgress(mySeekBar.getProgress()-1); Doing that I force a move, but stay in the same position. –  Derzu"***